# bower install package with custom directory structure

Tags: bower, bower-install

how to install js-package using bower with following directories structure:

```
package-name
----version
--------files
```

by default directories structure is:

```
bower_components
----package-name
--------files
```

after modifying `.bowerrc`

```
{
    "directory": ""
}
```

directories looks like:

```
----package-name
--------files
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way of achieving this directory layout out of the box.
You might be able to achieve this by post processing the downloaded components.
One option is using a Bower postinstall [hook](https://github.com/bower/bower/blob/master/HOOKS.md) which will rearrange the directory layout. The hook can get a list of all components downloaded by Bower. You will need to figure out which component  version was downloaded. You can get this information from the `.bower.json` which is created by Bower at resolution time (do not confuse with bower.json). Notice that this file is used internally by Bower and may be subject to change.
You can achieve the same results with various available grunt tasks, for example the [grunt-bower-task](https://github.com/yatskevich/grunt-bower-task). Again the challenge would be getting the resolved version of the components.